# A first chance exception of type 'System.SystemException' when retargeted cordova windows phone 8 app to Windows phone silverlight 8.1

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows phone app using cordova 3.4.  I have retargeted my app to Windows phone silverlight 8.1 to include videolibrary in capability. When running the app it causing exception as below-

A first chance exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll
Error calling js to fire nativeReady event. Did you include cordova.js in your html script tag?

A first chance exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll

Error calling js to add appExit funtion.

deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

Channel not fired: onNativeReady

Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

And device ready event not firing. I am using Visual studio 2013.

Thanks in advance.